# My href link wont work

Tags: javascript, html

My href link wont work, and the thing is, I've copied some `Javascript` code for my twitter button (twitter gives out the code for free) into my website, but I don't ACTUALLY know `Javascript`, only basic `Html`.

Can someone check out the following code and make sure its okay? The part that isn't working is the line of code mentioning `"Click here for a list of older posts!"`.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Curiosity Killed the Cat</title>
<!-- But Satisfaction Brought it Back. -->
</head>
<body>

<h1 style="font-size:160%;">If Curiosity Can Kill, Then i'm Not Afraid to        Die.</h1>
<hr>
<h2>Upload Number Two 6/4/16</h2>
<a href="aceidaltest.comlu.com/directories/">Click here for a list of older posts!</a>
<p> </p>
<pre> There have been</pre>
<!-- START OF HIT COUNTER CODE --><br><script language="JavaScript"     src="http://www.counter160.com/js.js?img=15"></script><br><a href="https://www.000webhost.com"><img src="http://www.counter160.com/images/15/left.png" alt="Free web hosting" border="0" align="texttop"></a><a href="http://www.hosting24.com"><img alt="Web hosting" src="http://www.counter160.com/images/15/right.png" border="0" align="texttop"></a><!-- END OF HIT COUNTER CODE -->
<pre> different users that have visited this website.</pre>
</body>
<!-- Follow Button -->
<a href="https://twitter.com/aceidal" class="twitter-follow-button" data-show-count="false" data-size="large">Follow @aceidal</a>
<script>!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],p=/^http:/.test(d.location)?'http':'https';if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src=p+'://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js';fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document, 'script', 'twitter-wjs');   </script>
<!-- Tweet Button -->
<a href="https://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button" data-text="Check out this website/blog!" data-size="large" data-related="aceidal" data-hashtags="satisfactionbroughtitback">Tweet</a>
<script>!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],p=/^http:/.test(d.location)?'http':'https';if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src=p+'://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js';fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document, 'script', 'twitter-wjs'); </script>

</html>
```

Comment: Look at the syntax highlighting, it should be a big clue. Use an IDE that highlights syntax as well, then it will be harder to make mistakes like this.

Answer (score 1):

**Corrected Answer:** (see comment)

The link you provided is acting as a relative path. Append `http://` to it and it should work as expected.

```
<a href="http://aceidaltest.comlu.com/directories/">
```

---

You need to end the html comments correctly:

```
<!-- Comment -->
```

not

```
<!-- Comment --!>
```

Comment: Oh thank you! That wasnt even my code. I just copied it. Blame 000webhost Didnt really fix the problem though.

Comment: This code is working properly. What you suggested has nothing to do with it.

Comment: My apologies, that was the first thing I noticed. The link you provided is acting as a relative path. Append `http://` to it and it should work as expected.
    `<a href="http://aceidaltest.comlu.com/directories/">`